Erasing incorrectly encoded byte sequences on reading
I am reading files into Ruby strings, and these strings are later processed further (for instance, using the CSV module). The external encoding of the files is a parameter, and supposedly, the files to be processed should be of that specified encoding.
During reading, I convert the files from the supposed external encoding into UTF-8.
Occasionally,  I get erroneous files which are encoded in a different way than the specified encoding.
Of course if the encoding is wrong, my program will read only garbage, but if the encoding is not only wrong, but even contains byte sequences which are illegal under the supposed encoding, I will get an exception when processing the file.
The specification requires that those byte sequences, which can not be deciphered due to incorrect encoding, should be simply removed from the input file instead of causing the program to abort.
To implement this, I am reading a file into a string like this:
 UTF8_CONVERTER = ->(field) { field.encode('utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: "") }

read_flags = {
   external_encoding: ext_enc, # i.e. Encoding::ISO_8859_1
   internal_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8,
   converters: UTF8_CONVERTER
}

file_content = IO.read(file_path, read_flags)

IMO, this should make a file_content a valid string which is UTF-8 encoded. If my program later decides that this string should be CSV parsed, it invokes the csv parser like this:
e_enc = file_content.encoding
i_enc = Encoding::UTF_8
...
csv_opt = { col_sep: ';', row_sep: :auto, external_encoding: e_enc, internal_encoding: i_enc}
CSV.foreach(file_content, csv_opt) { .... }

The reason why I redundantly specify the encoding here too, is, that the method which is processing the CSV, has a general purpose, and also should work if Strings have a different encoding.
However, this does not work:
If I am processing a file which is supposed to be UTF-8 (i.e. ext_enc equals Encoding::UTF_8), but in reality was encoded in for instance Windows-1252, and there  are some byte sequence in it, which would be illegal under UTF, CSV.foreach raises the exception ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.
I conclude from this, that my UTF8_CONVERTER did not remove the incorrect bytes.
Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?
UPDATE
@Stefan pointed out in his comment, that the converter option can't be used in IO.read and suggested that I pass the conversion option directly. This does not work either (I have to use JRuby 1.7.21, which is equivalent to Ruby 1.9.3). I could at least create a small, reproducible example:
I create a file illegal.txt, with the following content:
> xxd illegal.txt
00000000: 66fc 720a                                f.r.

We can see that it contains the byte sequence FC 72, which is not legal UTF-8.
Now I read the file with
fc=IO.read('illegal.txt', {:external_encoding=>#<Encoding:UTF-8>, :internal_encoding=>#<Encoding:UTF-8>, :invalid=>:replace, :undef=>:replace, :replace=>""}

I would have expected, that this would have removed at least the FC, so that the resulting string would be "fr\n", or maybe just "f\n". However, when I do a
puts fc.bytes.to_a

I still see [102, 252, 114, 10] printed.

I don't see where CSV accepts external_encoding and internal_encoding, only encoding maybe try encoding: "#{e_enc}:UTF-8"

From the Docs: "This method optionally accepts an additional :encoding option that you can use to specify the Encoding of the data read from path or io. You must provide this unless your data is in the encoding given by Encoding::default_external. Parsing will use this to determine how to parse the data. You may provide a second Encoding to have the data transcoded as it is read. For example, 'UTF-32BE:UTF-8'
would read UTF-32BE data from the file but transcode it to UTF-8 before parsing.
"

You pass a converters: option to IO.read, but that is a CSV option. IO accepts open options and encoding options, but no "converters" (it doesn't operate on fields). Try passing the encoding options (invalid:, undef:, replace:) directly. Also pass keyword arguments, i.e. IO.read(file_path, **read_flags) unless you are using an old Ruby version.

@Stefan: I am using an old Ruby. I will try out your suggestion. Perhaps you could already post your comment as an answer,. If your idea works, I will then accept the answer.

@Stefan : Your solution did not work for me. See the update in my question, where I posted a reprducible example.

When reading the file via IO.read, you have to specify the external encoding as ASCII and the internal encoding as UTF-8 in order to replace invalid or undefined byte sequences: (I'm using '_' as a replacement string for demonstration purposes here, empty string works as well)
data = IO.read('invalid.txt', encoding: 'ASCII:UTF-8',
                                 undef: :replace,
                               invalid: :replace,
                               replace: '_')

data          #=> "f_r\n"
data.bytes    #=> [102, 95, 114, 10]
data.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

Altenatively, you can binread the file:
data = IO.binread('invalid.txt')

data          #=> "f\xFCr\n"
data.bytes    #=> [102, 252, 114, 10]
data.encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

... and encode! the string afterwards:
data.encode!('utf-8', undef: :replace, invalid: :replace, replace: '_')

data          #=> "f_r\n"
data.bytes    #=> [102, 95, 114, 10]
data.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>


Looks great! What is 'ASCII::UTF-8', compared to Encoding::ASCII_8BIT and Encoding::UTF_8 (except that you describe the encoding using a String, and I using a Encoding object)?.

There's no difference, it's just a shorthand for specifying the external and internal encoding, see Open Options

Perhaps this depends on the Ruby version. If I do a Encoding.find('ASCII::UTF-8') or Encoding.find('ASCII-UTF-8'), I get an exception with the message unknown encoding name, while i.e. Encoding.find('ASCII-8BIT') works.

The shorthand format is 'external:internal', i.e. encoding: 'ASCII:UTF-8' specifies two encodings at once: 'ASCII' as external and 'UTF-8' as internal encoding. To pass them separately as Encoding instances, use external_encoding: Encoding::ASCII, internal_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8

I found a solution, but it is so ugly, that I hope that someone comes up with a better idea:
Based on the example code in my question, I have reat the content of the file illegal.txt into the string variable fc, which still contains the illegal byte sequence FC 72.
To remove the offending FC, I can do a
fc.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
fc_fixed = fc.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, undef: :replace, replace: '')

After this, puts fc_fixed.bytes.to_a displays 102, 114, 10].
The additional force_encoding step is needed, because fc already has encoding UTF-8, and, at least in my Ruby version, fc.encode would then simply leave everything in place.
